# How are "Owner-Produced Parts" handled under FAA regulations?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

[FAR 21.9](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&n=pt14.1.21&r=PART&ty=HTML#se14.1.21_19) provides the ability to install parts that were "Produced by an owner or operator for maintaining or altering that owner or operator's product". This seems like a pretty broad scope of authority for aircraft owners.

Under what circumstances are owner-produced parts typically used, and what requirements are imposed on the part (and the owner producing it)?

Comment: What kind of part? A 3D-printed plastic seat belt holder for your Cessna will receive one level of inspection, a hand-forged fan blade for a Trent 970 will receive a bit more scrutiny.

Comment: and a piece of duct tape to cover the hole in the wing of your Cessna, hmmm.  (and yes, I've seen that, had I known more about aircraft maintenance requirements at the time I'd not have climbed on board that thing...).

Comment: Wasn't duct tape. There is an FAA-approved product called speed tape that looks almost identical ( 2 inches wide, silver ) and is commonly used for temporary repairs. If you've never seen the proper stuff up close you won't know the difference.

Comment: @paul if there's a difference describe it in your answer. (As far as I'm aware there isn't: you have to demonstrate equivalence in either case...)

Comment: Duct tape from Home Depot and aerospace-grade aluminized adhesive tape from 3M are not equivalent in any way other than both are tape, and 2 inches wide.

Comment: @paul I was responding to your first comment where you assert there are different levels of inspection - is this by regulation, in an AC, etc.?  The use of speed tape is *not at all relevant to this question* (as far as I'm aware neither speed tape nor duct tape qualifies as an owner-produced part under the FARs), but it might be an interesting subject for a [separate question & answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ah - misunderstood the target (your comment appeared right under the duct tape). My experience with the relevant authorities shows they really don't care about largely cosmetic but still technically "requiring certification" parts on light aircraft. We made our own interior panels for a Cessna 206 and the comment was "nice job". The step bolted over the wheel required a field-approved STC.

Comment: A while back I needed to replace a flap track on my old Cessna 340.  The company that produced them was still in business, but did not have the part.  I had them produced the part according to their specs.  I received a traveler (the little white card) for it, that said the item was produced at the owner's direction referencing the FAR above and their STC.  My A&P replaced the existing track with the new part and made an entry in the log book stating that they replaced the old track with a new track manufactured per the FAR.  I had a FAA review of the logs at a later date with no issues.

Comment: @paul not to be confused with the silvery metallic tape you can get at the hardware which I cannot find the name of but presumably isn't aviation certified?

Comment: @Michael If you're talking about the stuff you're *supposed* to use on duct work (which is actually metal tape) we call that "HVAC Tape", "Foil Tape", or "Alumatape". (Like "duct tape" this generally isn't something you'd use for exterior repairs, but 3M makes at least one line of it (3M 433 tape) that's suitable for use on cabin duct work.)

Comment: @voretaq7 Yes, that's it!  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adhesive_tapes) lists speed tape but not any of those names for HVAC tape.  And why people use Duct Tape for ducts (or why it's even called that) I have no idea - it's absolutely rotten for ducts IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [July/August 2002 edition](http://www.faa.gov/news/safety_briefing/2002/media/julyAug2002.pdf) of FAAviation News (now [FAA Safety Briefing](http://www.faa.gov/news/safety_briefing/)) has a detailed article on owner-produced parts, including advice on best practices if you want to make your own parts. It does confirm that owners have very broad authority to do so, provided that they document everything properly.

Typical reasons for producing your own parts are (I've paraphrased them from the article here):

- The aircraft has been out of production for years
- The aircraft is an orphan without a Type Certificate
- There is no technical support because the aircraft is so old
- There may be long delays in getting parts from the manufacturer
- The price of official parts is extremely high

As for requirements of the part itself, the article list four characteristics that a part must have:

> 1. The part must be properly designed
> 2. The part must be produced to conform to the design
> 3. The part's production must be properly documented
> 4. The part must be properly maintained

The owner must be involved in the production but doesn't actually have to do the manufacturing himself:

> The aircraft owner must participate in the manufacture of the part
> in at least one of five ways for it to be considered an Owner Produced
> Part.
>
> 1. The owner provides the manufacturer of the part with the design or performance data.
> 2. The owner provides the manufacturer of the part with the materials.
> 3. The owner provides the manufacturer with fabrication processes or assembly methods.
> 4. The owner provides the manufacturer of the part with quality control procedures.
> 5. The owner personally supervises the manufacture of the new part.

More recently, in the September 2014 edition of the [Cessna Pilots Association](http://www.cessna.org/) magazine, [Mike Busch](http://www.savvyaviator.com/) has an article on replacement parts that calls the current regulations on owner produced parts "extremely liberal":

> “Owner-produced parts” do not require a  PMA. These are parts produced
> by an aircraft  owner for use on his own aircraft, and not  offered
> for sale. There is an FAA letter of  interpretation that sets forth
> precisely what  an owner's involvement must be to qualify a  part as
> “owner-produced,” and it is extremely  liberal. The owner need not
> actually  manufacture the part himself, so long as  he provides
> specifications or materials  or supervision or some other meaningful
> participation in the part's production.

Unfortunately, he didn't mention exactly which letter of interpretation covers these parts but the FAA magazine article refers to an "FAA Memorandum dated
August 5, 1993" and I guess it's probably the same one. I wasn't able to find it on the [FAA site](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/Interpretations/).

Comment: Mike Busch's EAA article, https://resources.savvyaviation.com/wp-content/uploads/articles_eaa/EAA_2011-08_owner-produced-parts.pdf, suggests that the memo is from April 5th 1993. Could the date discrepancy explain why the original memo eluded your search?

Comment: Found the elusive memo, available for download here: http://www.velocolutions.com/FAA-owner-manufactured-part.pdf