# Can a non-A&P fabricate and install his own hydraulic lines?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-systems

As a non-A&P, am I allowed to fabricate and install hydraulic fluid lines as part of preventive maintenance on an aircraft?

Comment: Is your aircraft type-certified or experimental?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30503/discussion-between-voretaq7-and-tyler-durden).

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking someone who does not hold a mechanic's certificate may not fabricate their own hardlines or hoses, nor may they replace hardlines. This work must be done by someone holding the appropriate Airframe and/or Powerplant mechanic rating.

An owner/operator with a private pilot certificate may install prefabricated flexible fluid carrying hoses (*with the specific exception of hydraulic hoses*) as preventive maintenance,as allowed under [FAR 43 Appendix A](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?mc=true&node=ap14.1.43_117.a&rgn=div9).

---

There are three notable exceptions to the above general statements:

- An owner of a Special Light Sport aircraft may acquire a repairman certificate, enabling them to perform this kind of work on their aircraft.
- The builder of an Experimental Amateur-Built aircraft ("homebuilt") may perform this work on aircraft they have built, as FAR 43 does not govern maintenance on aircraft with an Experimental airworthiness certificate.
- If working under the supervision of an A&P mechanic you are authorized to perform any work your supervisor is authorized for (per [FAR 43.3 (d)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?mc=true&node=se14.1.43_13&rgn=div8), and subject to some specific requirements).

Comment: Wouldn't an owner be able to fabricate them as [owner-produced parts](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8409/62)?

Comment: @Pondlife That's true - there is a 4th exception in that you could go the owner-produced parts route for pretty much anything if you own the aircraft, have the resources to properly make the part, and your mechanic considers it airworthy & will install it. (Hydraulic lines might be stretch for this depending on the system's rated working pressure, though I suppose if you custom-order hoses from Aeroquip or someone they're technically "owner-produced" because you're providing the specifications).