# Can a pilot or owner repair a seatbelt?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

I have a Cessna 210 with inertia reel seatbelts.  The spring coil on the retention wheel broke.

- FAR 43, Appendix A (C).14 allows for owner replacement of seat belts
- FAR 43.13.(b) requires that it be restored at least to its original
  or properly altered condition.
- and FAR 21.9.(a).5  allows a part produced by an owner / operator to be installed

so... can I as owner / operator:

- repair the spring and re-install the seatbelt
  or
- purchase a used seatbelt with a working coil spring (but no good webbing) and replace the coil spring?

Comment: FAR 43 is meant to allow the owner/operator to replace bolt-on components. What you are asking is the repair of the mechanism itself which may not be allowed. I think it would be worth a call to your local FSDO for an official decision.

Comment: Related https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/how-are-owner-produced-parts-handled-under-faa-regulations?rq=1.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot repair a seat belt. You can only replace it.

An owner-operator can perform preventative maintenance on their aircraft. That includes **replacement** of the seats and/or seat belts.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a part may be manufactured by the owner.  However, your part will be subject of an annual inspection at which time an IA mechanic may reject the airworthiness of your part.

Your repair and installation will require your logbook entry.  As an airframe mechanic, I would review recent maintenance and be looking for a return to service tag from an approved repair station.  I would not be inclined to accept an owner-repaired reel assembly as airworthy.